# How to response with specific json attribute

Tags: python, http, flask, slack

I'm trying to set up a webhook for [slack](https://api.slack.com/apis/connections/events-api). There i need to return "challenge" attribute value to the request below. I don't know what to write in "response = make_response((),200)" to response correctly.

```
{
    "token": "Jhj5dZrVaK7ZwHHjRyZWjbDl",
    "challenge": "3eZbrw1aBm2rZgRNFdxV2595E9CY3gmdALWMmHkvFXO7tYXAYM8P",
    "type": "url_verification"
}


import os
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import make_response

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/webhook2')
def hello_slack():
    request_json = request.get_json(silent=True, force=True)
    response_body = json.dumps(request_json)
    response = make_response((),200)
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
    return response

if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = int(os.getenv('PORT', 5000))
    app.run(debug=False, port=port, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Comment: Can you link to a more specific section of the docs which mentions returning this challenge?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I see you have a dict just sitting there at the top of the file; that seems odd. I would guess you want to have some variable equal that dict and response should use variable[“challenge”]